# IOS - convertion BGRASampleBuffer To RGB Crash

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, crash, buffer

I'm trying to convert a CMSampleBufferRef to a cv::Mat Matrix in order then to apply some computer vision algorithm.

I don't know why, but the app crash almost immediately.

Concerning the context, I cannot use the simulator because the app works only with a specific device (Structure Sensor) that I plugged into the Ipad. Therefore, I cannot debug with XCode as usual with IOS App.

But I was able to get the crash log inside this folder:

> /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

And I used the following command line to symbolicate the log as I could not understand the error message.

```
symbolicate Scanner.crash Scanner.app
```

My log revealed essentially this:

> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001033d4000 Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0
>   Scanner                         0x000000010010bc30
>   convertBGRASampleBufferToRGB(opaqueCMSampleBuffer*, cv::Mat&)
>   (ViewController.mm:766) 1   Scanner
>     0x000000010010bbf0
>   convertBGRASampleBufferToRGB(opaqueCMSampleBuffer*, cv::Mat&)
>   (ViewController.mm:757) 2   Scanner
>     0x00000001001050e0 -[ViewController(Sensor)
>   sensorDidOutputSynchronizedDepthFrame:andColorFrame:]
>   (ViewController+Sensor.mm:404) 3   Scanner
>     0x000000010012090c 0x1000ec000 + 215308 4   Foundation
>     0x0000000181898510 _NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ +
>   16 5   Foundation                     0x00000001817ea900
>   -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96 6   Foundation                      0x00000001817daed8 -[**NSOperationInternal _start:] + 604 7
>
>   Foundation                        0x000000018189a904 __NSOQSchedule_f +
>   224 8   libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000018092947c
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16 9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018092eb84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844 10 
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000180e94dd8
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 12 11  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000180e92c40 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1628 12  CoreFoundation                   0x0000000180dbcd10
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 13  GraphicsServices
>     0x00000001826a4088 GSEventRunModal + 180 14  UIKit
>     0x0000000186089f70 UIApplicationMain + 204 15  Scanner
>     0x000000010010d2d8 main (main.m:15) 16  libdyld.dylib
>     0x000000018095a8b8 start + 4

Here the piece of code :

```
void convertBGRASampleBufferToRGB (CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer, cv::Mat& dest)
{

    CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

    dest.create((int)height, (int)width, CV_8UC3);
     //    NSLog(@"Image width: %d Image heigth: %d ", dest.cols, dest.rows);


    unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*) CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);

    // Use NEON to convert from BGRA to RGB, or use Accelerate in the case that we're on simulator
#ifdef __ARM_NEON__

    NSLog(@"Use NEON ");
         //Crash here
    uint8_t* sourcePtr = (uint8_t*)ptr;
    uint8_t* destPtr = (uint8_t*)dest.data;

    const int numPixels = (int)(width*height);

    int pixel = 0;
    for (; pixel < numPixels; pixel += 16)
    {
        //Crash here
        uint8x16x4_t sourcePixelsBGRA = vld4q_u8((const unsigned char*)sourcePtr);
        uint8x16x3_t sourceRGB;
        sourceRGB.val[0] = sourcePixelsBGRA.val[2];
        sourceRGB.val[1] = sourcePixelsBGRA.val[1];
        sourceRGB.val[2] = sourcePixelsBGRA.val[0];
        vst3q_u8((unsigned char *)destPtr, sourceRGB);

        sourcePtr += 16*4;
        destPtr += 16*3;

    }

    // Convert any leftover pixels (15 or less would remain, if any)
    for (; pixel < numPixels; pixel++) {
        uint8_t* sourceBGRAPixel = sourcePtr;
        uint8_t* destRGBPixel = destPtr;

        destRGBPixel[0] = sourceBGRAPixel[2];
        destRGBPixel[1] = sourceBGRAPixel[1];
        destRGBPixel[2] = sourceBGRAPixel[0];

        sourcePtr += 4;
        destPtr += 3;
    }

#else
    NSLog(@"Not Use NEON ");
    vImage_Buffer src;
    src.width = width;
    src.height = height;
    src.data = ptr;
    src.rowBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);

    vImage_Buffer destImage;
    destImage.width = width;
    destImage.height = height;
    destImage.rowBytes = width*3;
    destImage.data = dest.data;

    vImage_Error err;
    err = vImageConvert_BGRA8888toRGB888(&src, &destImage, kvImageNoFlags);
    if(err != kvImageNoError){
        NSLog(@"Error in Pixel Copy vImage_error %ld", err);
    }


#endif


    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

}
```

And actually, according to the log, it crashed here:

```
 uint8_t* sourcePtr = (uint8_t*)ptr;
```

and

```
 vst3q_u8((unsigned char *)destPtr, sourceRGB);
```

I tried to understand but impossible to figure out why.

Any help would be great !
Thank you very much in advance,

Best regards,